# Representing ISO 8601 year-month dates documentation with Swagger

Tags: java, swagger, wildfly, openapi, resteasy

How to make Swagger core generate openapi.json documentation with a Year-Month field represented as String?

In code I already tried `@JsonFormat` and `@JsonbDateFormat`.

Returned entity is correctly represented as String, with correct format, but documentation always is generated as Object.

Environment:

- io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-jaxrs2 2.1.9
- wildfly 21.0.2
- java 11

Here a snippet:

```java
@JsonbDateFormat(value = "uuuu-MM") // or "yyyy-MM", or @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "uuuu-MM")
private YearMonth reference;
```

Entity return:

```json
{
    "reference": "2020-11",
}
```

Documentation generated:

```json
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  ...
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "Entity" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "reference" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "year" : {
                "type" : "integer",
                "format" : "int32"
              },
              "month" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "enum" : [ "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER" ]
              },
              "monthValue" : {
                "type" : "integer",
                "format" : "int32"
              },
              "leapYear" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Swagger core do not use `@JsonFormat` or `@JsonbDateFormat` as source for formatting template, it uses only attributes types, but it do not have a default for YearMonth type.

So, it's possible to define data representation with Swagger Annotation `@Schema`.

In this particular case: `@Schema(type = "string", format = "yearmonth", example = "2020-07")`

Also, to use a default custom schema, see [How to set a default custom schema for types in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519615/how-to-set-a-default-custom-schema-for-types-in-swagger)